# How to return results based on day of query run in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd, datepart

[image]I have an issue I cannot seem to wrap me head around using SQL Server. I have a forecast amount which is done at a monthly level.  I need a query that would calculate the remaining forecast based on the day I run the query.  I was trying with `DATEPART`, `DATEADD`, & `DATEDIFF`but had no luck.  Anybody have a way they have found to do something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at using `GETDATE`

Comment: You really need some sample data and desired results.  There are countless ways to calculate and present something like this

Comment: I have added a graphic with what the data would look like.  Say I run it on the 13th (highlighted) - I want to return only the total quantity of forecast for that day forward to the end of the month.  Some months have 30 days, some 31 (and of course 28).  I was trying to figure out something that could do that calculation no matter what day I run the query.

Comment: I assume that on the 5th day of February in a non leap year you would want to multiple your total monthly figure by 5 / 28? (or maybe 4 / 28 since the 4th day isn't finished). Please confirm / explain what rule you want to apply and perhaps we can help.

Comment: really I am just trying to narrow the date selection to between whatever day of the month I run the query and the last day of the given month.  The calculation of quantity would be correct if I can get that down.  I am trying to avoid hard-coding so that it can be run on demand by anybody

Comment: I'm not proposing you hard code anything, just trying to get to the bottom of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To at least get you started "wrapping your head around" things here is an approach that could be taken assuming that you use some code "language" to access the SQL Server database.  Here is some easy-to-understand classic ASP code to calc a FractionToUse variable would could then be used for multiplying in the SQL statement:

```
FirstDayOfCurMonthDate = DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)
CurrentDate = Date()
FinalDayOfCurMonthDate = DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 1, 1 - 1)

DaysInCurMonthRemaining = DateDiff("D", CurrentDate, FinalDayOfCurMonthDate) + 1
DaysInCurMonthTotal = DateDiff("D", FirstDayOfCurMonthDate, FinalDayOfCurMonthDate) + 1

FractionToUse = DaysInCurMonthRemaining / DaysInCurMonthTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have stumbled upon the answer I was looking for...it is kind of clunky but achieves what I was after - to narrow my dates from the day of the query run to the end of that month: `BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)+1, 0))`

Comment: If you want something less clunky try `EOMONTH` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017